# Django website deploy error: Failed building wheel for Pillow, Reportlab in cPanel

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library, virtualenv, cpanel

**I am trying to use xhtml to pdf libray my code is on goddady cpanel.**
i have tried
pip install reportlab
pip install xhtml2pdf
pip install --pre xhtml2pdf

**and no one works**

non of these commands works on the cpanel i am very sad for the errors they are not disappering i tried soo many things

only
pip install pillow==8.0.0
works

````
      copying src/reportlab/fonts/zy______.pfb -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/reportlab/fonts
      running build_ext
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/rl_addons
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/rl_addons/rl_accel
      /usr/bin/gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/include -I/opt/alt/python37/include/python3.7m -c src/rl_addons/rl_accel/_rl_accel.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/rl_addons/rl_accel/_rl_accel.o
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed: Permission denied
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for reportlab
  Running setup.py clean for reportlab
Failed to build Pillow reportlab
Installing collected packages: Pillow, oscrypto, lxml, importlib-metadata, html5lib, future, tzlocal, reportlab, cssselect2, click, arabic-reshaper, svglib, pyhanko-certvalidator, pyHanko, xhtml2pdf
  Attempting uninstall: Pillow
    Found existing installation: Pillow 8.0.0
    Uninstalling Pillow-8.0.0:
      Successfully uninstalled Pillow-8.0.0
  Running setup.py install for Pillow ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for Pillow did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [130 lines of output]
      running install
      /home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:37: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        setuptools.SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning,
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/BlpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/DdsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      running egg_info
      warning: no files found matching '*.c'
      warning: no files found matching '*.h'
      warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
      warning: no files found matching '*.txt'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.clang-format'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
      writing manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      running build_ext
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src
      /usr/bin/gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-install-uzv1euwl/pillow_7caad568e8504a3c9cd14a3487098422 -I/usr/include -I/home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/include -I/opt/alt/python37/include/python3.7m -c src/_imagingft.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/_imagingft.o
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/libImaging
      /usr/bin/gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-install-uzv1euwl/pillow_7caad568e8504a3c9cd14a3487098422 -I/usr/include -I/home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/include -I/opt/alt/python37/include/python3.7m -c src/_imagingmath.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/_imagingmath.o
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/Tk
      /usr/bin/gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-install-uzv1euwl/pillow_7caad568e8504a3c9cd14a3487098422 -I/usr/include -I/home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/include -I/opt/alt/python37/include/python3.7m -c src/Tk/tkImaging.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/Tk/tkImaging.o
      /usr/bin/gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-install-uzv1euwl/pillow_7caad568e8504a3c9cd14a3487098422 -I/usr/include -I/home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/include -I/opt/alt/python37/include/python3.7m -c src/_imagingmorph.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/_imagingmorph.o
      /usr/bin/gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -DHAVE_XCB -DPILLOW_VERSION=\"9.2.0\" -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-install-uzv1euwl/pillow_7caad568e8504a3c9cd14a3487098422 -I/usr/include -I/home/udowyxdf/virtualenv((downloader:3.7)) [udowyxdf@server225 downloader]$ pip install xhtml2pdfCollecting xhtml2pdf
  Using cached xhtml2pdf-0.2.8-py3-none-any.whl (256 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: PyPDF3>=1.0.5 in /home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (
from xhtml2pdf) (1.0.6)
Collecting arabic-reshaper>=2.1.0
  Using cached arabic_reshaper-2.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Collecting Pillow>=8.1.1
  Using cached Pillow-9.2.0.tar.gz (50.0 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting pyhanko-certvalidator>=0.19.5
  Using cached pyhanko_certvalidator-0.19.5-py3-none-any.whl (70 kB)
Collecting html5lib>=1.0.1
  Using cached html5lib-1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112 kB)
Collecting reportlab>=3.5.53
  Using cached reportlab-3.6.11.tar.gz (4.5 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting pyHanko>=0.12.1
  Using cached pyHanko-0.14.0-py3-none-any.whl (355 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: python-bidi>=0.4.2 in /home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packa
ges (from xhtml2pdf) (0.4.2)
Collecting svglib>=1.2.1
  Using cached svglib-1.4.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting future
  Using cached future-0.18.2-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from arabic-reshaper>=2.1.0->xhtml2pdf) (60.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: webencodings in /home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from html5lib>=1.0.1->xhtml2pdf) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9 in /home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (fromhtml5lib>=1.0.1->xhtml2pdf) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: asn1crypto>=1.5.1 in /home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pyHanko>=0.12.1->xhtml2pdf) (1.5.1)
Collecting tzlocal>=2.1
  Using cached tzlocal-4.2-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=3.3.1 in /home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/lib64/python3.7/site-packages (from pyHanko>=0.12.1->xhtml2pdf) (37.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in /home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pyHanko>=0.12.1->xhtml2pdf) (2022.1)
Requirement already satisfied: qrcode>=6.1 in /home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pyHanko>=0.12.1->xhtml2pdf) (7.3.1)
Collecting click>=7.1.2
  Using cached click-8.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml>=5.3.1 in /home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/lib64/python3.7/site-packages (from pyHanko>=0.12.1->xhtml2pdf) (6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.24.0 in /home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pyHanko>=0.12.1->xhtml2pdf) (2.27.1)
Requirement already satisfied: uritools>=3.0.1 in /home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pyhanko-certvalidator>=0.19.5->xhtml2pdf) (4.0.0)
Collecting oscrypto>=1.1.0
  Using cached oscrypto-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (194 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in /home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from PyPDF3>=1.0.5->xhtml2pdf) (4.64.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tinycss2>=0.6.0 in /home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from svglib>=1.2.1->xhtml2pdf) (1.1.1)
Collecting cssselect2>=0.2.0
  Using cached cssselect2-0.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting lxml
  Using cached lxml-4.9.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.whl (5.6 MB)
Collecting importlib-metadata
  Using cached importlib_metadata-4.12.0-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.12 in /home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/lib64/python3.7/site-packages (from cryptography>=3.3.1->pyHanko>=0.12.1->xhtml2pdf) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in /home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.24.0->pyHanko>=0.12.1->xhtml2pdf) (2.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.24.0->pyHanko>=0.12.1->xhtml2pdf) (1.26.9)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.24.0->pyHanko>=0.12.1->xhtml2pdf) (3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests>=2.24.0->pyHanko>=0.12.1->xhtml2pdf) (2022.5.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz-deprecation-shim in /home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tzlocal>=2.1->pyHanko>=0.12.1->xhtml2pdf) (0.1.0.post0)
Requirement already satisfied: backports.zoneinfo in /home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/lib64/python3.7/site-packages (from tzlocal>=2.1->pyHanko>=0.12.1->xhtml2pdf) (0.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography>=3.3.1->pyHanko>=0.12.1->xhtml2pdf) (2.21)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.6.4 in /home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from importlib-metadata->click>=7.1.2->pyHanko>=0.12.1->xhtml2pdf) (4.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in /home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from importlib-metadata->click>=7.1.2->pyHanko>=0.12.1->xhtml2pdf) (3.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: tzdata in /home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from pytz-deprecation-shim->tzlocal>=2.1->pyHanko>=0.12.1->xhtml2pdf) (2022.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: Pillow, reportlab
  Building wheel for Pillow (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [127 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      running egg_info
      warning: no files found matching '*.c'
      warning: no files found matching '*.h'
      warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
      warning: no files found matching '*.txt'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.clang-format'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
      writing manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      running build_ext
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/Tk
      /usr/bin/gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-install-o3ldcnqi/pillow_3e1b94e31bbf47bb83efa30b01bd308e -I/usr/include -I/home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/include -I/opt/alt/python37/include/python3.7m -c src/_imagingmath.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/_imagingmath.o
      /usr/bin/gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-install-o3ldcnqi/pillow_3e1b94e31bbf47bb83efa30b01bd308e -I/usr/include -I/home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/include -I/opt/alt/python37/include/python3.7m -c src/Tk/tkImaging.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/Tk/tkImaging.o

      copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/pdfpattern.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/reportlab/pdfbase
      copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata_enc_standard.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/reportlab/pdfbase
      copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata_widths_symbol.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/reportlab/pdfbase
      copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata_widths_courierboldoblique.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/reportlab/pdfbase
      copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata_enc_macexpert.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/reportlab/pdfbase
      copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/pdfform.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/reportlab/pdfbase
      copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/pdfutils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/reportlab/pdfbase
      copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata_widths_helveticaoblique.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/reportlab/pdfbase
      copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata_enc_symbol.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/reportlab/pdfbase
      copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata_widths_courier.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/reportlab/pdfbase
      copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata_widths_timesitalic.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/reportlab/pdfbase
      copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/cidfonts.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/reportlab/pdfbase
      copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata_widths_zapfdingbats.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/reportlab/pdfbase
      copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/reportlab/pdfbase
      copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_glyphlist.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/reportlab/pdfbase
      copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/acroform.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/reportlab/pdfbase
      copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/reportlab/pdfbase
      copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_can_cmap_data.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/reportlab/pdfbase
      copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata_widths_timesroman.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/reportlab/pdfbase
      copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata_widths_courierbold.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/reportlab/pdfbase
      copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata_enc_macroman.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/reportlab/pdfbase
      copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_cidfontdata.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/reportlab/pdfbase
      copying src/reportlab/pdfbase/_fontdata_enc_pdfdoc.py -> build/lib.linux-      copying src/reportlab/fonts/callig15.afm -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/reportlab/fonts
      running build_ext
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/rl_addons
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/rl_addons/rl_accel
      /usr/bin/gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/include -I/opt/alt/python37/include/python3.7m -c src/rl_addons/rl_accel/_rl_accel.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/rl_addons/rl_accel/_rl_accel.o
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed: Permission denied
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for reportlab
  Running setup.py clean for reportlab
Failed to build Pillow reportlab
Installing collected packages: Pillow, oscrypto, lxml, importlib-metadata, html5lib, future, tzlocal, reportlab, cssselect2, click, arabic-reshaper, svglib, pyhanko-certvalidator, pyHanko, xhtml2pdf
  Attempting uninstall: Pillow
    Found existing installation: Pillow 8.0.0
    Uninstalling Pillow-8.0.0:
      Successfully uninstalled Pillow-8.0.0
  Running setup.py install for Pillow ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for Pillow did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [130 lines of output]
      running install
      /home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:37: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        setuptools.SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning,
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL7

      copying src/PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PdfParser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
     ying src/PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      copying src/PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/PIL
      running egg_info
      warning: no files found matching '*.c'
      warning: no files found matching '*.h'
      warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
      warning: no files found matching '*.txt'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.clang-format'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
      writing manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      running build_ext
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src
      /usr/bin/gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-install-o3ldcnqi/pillow_3e1b94e31bbf47bb83efa30b01bd308e -I/usr/include -I/home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/include -I/opt/alt/python37/include/python3.7m -c src/_imagingft.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/_imagingft.o
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/Tk
      /usr/bin/gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-install-o3ldcnqi/pillow_3e1b94e31bbf47bb83efa30b01bd308e -I/usr/include -I/home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/include -I/opt/alt/python37/include/python3.7m -c src/Tk/tkImaging.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/Tk/tkImaging.o
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/libImaging
      /usr/bin/gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -DHAVE_XCB -DPILLOW_VERSION=\"9.2.0\" -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-install-o3ldcnqi/pillow_3e1b94e31bbf47bb83efa30b01bd308e -I/usr/include -I/home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/include -I/opt/alt/python37/include/python3.7m -c src/_imaging.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/_imaging.o
      /usr/bin/gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-install-o3ldcnqi/pillow_3e1b94e31bbf47bb83efa30b01bd308e -I/usr/include -I/home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/include -I/opt/alt/python37/include/python3.7m -c src/_imagingmath.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/_imagingmath.o
      /usr/bin/gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-install-o3ldcnqi/pillow_3e1b94e31bbf47bb83efa30b01bd308e -I/usr/include -I/home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/include -I/opt/alt/python37/include/python3.7m -c src/_imagingmorph.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/_imagingmorph.o
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed: Permission denied
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Rolling back uninstall of Pillow
  Moving to /home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/
   from /home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/~IL
  Moving to /home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/Pillow-8.0.0.dist-info/
   from /home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/~illow-8.0.0.dist-info
  Moving to /home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/Pillow.libs/
   from /home/udowyxdf/virtualenv/downloader/3.7/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/~illow.libs
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> Pillow

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
((downloader:3.7)) [udowyxdf@server225 downloader]$```


**I am trying to use xhtml to pdf libray my code is on goddady cpanel.**
i have tried 
pip install reportlab
pip install xhtml2pdf
pip install --pre xhtml2pdf

**and no one works**

non of these commands works on the cpanel i am very sad for the errors they are not disappering i tried soo many things

only 
pip install pillow==8.0.0
 works
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you try a different Python version. Also, make sure that you are entering into the virtual environment ( if using the Python Selector feature in cPanel ) before running the pip install. If you still find difficulties with the installation of the required modules, I would definitely recommend reaching out to your hosting provider's support team to check this out for you.